# Gatsby & GraphQL: Transforming a String field into markdown

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a GraphQL schema on a headless CMS. I'm using `gatsby-source-graphql` on a Gatsby site to get data from it.

There is a content field `MyType_BlogPost.body` of type `String`. This contains markdown code.

Is it possible to transform (with `gatsby-transformer-remark`) that into `MarkdownRemark` (or similar) so that it will automatically get subfields like `html` that contain the data one would expect (html code transformed from the markdown source)? I suspect subfields would be the way to do this, but I'm not 100 % of that.

I also suspect this could help but I'm not sure: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/

Thank you.

Comment: If your MyType_BlogPost.body contains HTML, you can convert that to Markdown using something like [turndown](https://github.com/domchristie/turndown) after it has been queried. 

Or are you actually wanting to change the GraphQL query such that it returns Markdown instead of the html which is currently stored in the .body field?

Comment: Hmm sorry, I think my question was vague. The body field contains markdown code which I would like to transform into html. Question fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If the field contains markdown code which you would like to transform into html, you should be able to do that using remark.

Remark is the library that `gatsby-transformer-remark` uses under the hood.

https://remark.js.org/

Specifically, look at the API section in their docs.

Comment: True. I thought about that possibility. But I first wanted to see if I could do this with schema customization. It would feel somehow a cleaner solution.

Comment: If you want to accomplish this with schema customization, [this section](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-custom-extensions) of the docs seems to indicate the way forward, and you can still use remark to do the job.